# Chrome doesn't remember last custom margin settings used

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I know that Chrome has default printing margin that is set to 0.4''. But I am using legal paper with 0.00'' top and bottom margin and 1.2'' in left and right. If I set this margin, every time I print, I don't have to repeat to set it. But now,Chrome doesnt remember the last custom margin setting that I used. Instead, back it to 0.40''. What is the best thing to do?

Comment: Fill a bugreport: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines